# Return bold/coloured search string from a function in javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, css

I am trying to write a name based search function in javascript. I have one function, where I am trying to match the search value with database. I have written regex for lower/upper case letter match. After the match is found (even the lower/upper) i need the matched string in BOLD/COLOURED letters, which is highlighted in main string.
e.g. In Bill if search string is, "bi" then returned value from main function should be **Bi**ll.
I have array of values, on which I am trying to execute my search function,
In my main function,

```
 reg = new RegExp(searchStr, 'gi');
for(var i=0; i<$scope.Arr.length ; i++)
            {
                strMatch = $scope.Arr.name.match(reg);
                tempName = $scope.Arr[i].name.replace(reg,dummy(strMatch[0]));
                console.log(tempName);
            }
```

I need help to write function dummy where I am trying to return Bold matched string,
I have tried it in this way,

```
 function dummy(str)
        {
            console.log(str);
            var newElement = "<span class='highlight'>" +str+ "</span>";
            console.log(newElement);
            return newElement;
        }
```

I am getting this output,

```
<span class='highlight'>Bi</span>ll
```

I need Bi as bold/highlighted.
This is my highlight class definition,

```
        .highlight
        {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said I need to bind the returned value to the array of object, and it was not possible to get the element ID for each changing value of an object, the solution for my problem was writing a **DIRECTIVE**.
I managed to solve it as given below,

```
.directive('ngCreateBoldString', function() {
    return {

        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            searchId : '@',
            searchString : '@',
            fromName : '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log('I am inside directive, this is value for search string:',$scope.searchString);
            console.log('This is value of whole Name:', $scope.fromName);
            var reg = new RegExp($scope.searchString, 'gi');
            $scope.getTemp = function(name) {
                var strMatch = name.match(reg);
                if(strMatch == null)
                {
                    return name;
                }
                console.log('I am matched string',strMatch[0]);
                var strDummy = "<b style='color:red'>" + strMatch[0] + "</b>" ;
                console.log(strDummy);
                return name.replace(reg,strDummy);
            };
        }],
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
            var dumCheck = scope.getTemp(scope.fromName);
            console.log('I am a dumcheck!',dumCheck);
            dumCheck= "<h3 style='font-size:180%'>"+dumCheck+"</h3>";
            console.log('I am going to print this!!',dumCheck);
            iAttrs.fromName = dumCheck;
            scope.$watch('fromName', function(newVal) {
                var m= document.getElementById(scope.searchId);
                console.log('I am var m');
                m.innerHTML =dumCheck;

            });
        }

    };
})
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there, except that you're missing the array index when setting `strMatch`.

```
strMatch = $scope.Arr[i].name.match(reg);
```

**Edit:**

You might also want to only perform the highlighting conditionally. I suggesting checking whether `strMatch` exists (using `if(strMatch){...}`) before performing the replacement on `tempName`.

I also don't recommend using `console.log` for testing this kind of code, since you're trying to generate HTML (which the console can't really display in a useful way). Why not append the generated HTML to an existing HTML element so you can see the real results?

Check out the updated example code below.

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  var searchStr = this.value;
  if (searchStr.length > 0) {
    var reg = new RegExp(searchStr, 'gi');
    var $scope = {
      Arr: [{
        name: "Bill Clinton"
      }, {
        name: "Bob Dole"
      }, {
        name: "Bilbo Baggins"
      }, {
        name: "Bing Crosby"
      }, {
        name: "Frodo Baggins"
      }]
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Arr.length; i++) {
      var strMatch = $scope.Arr[i].name.match(reg);
      var tempName = $scope.Arr[i].name;
      if (strMatch) {
        var tempName = tempName.replace(strMatch[0], dummy(strMatch[0]));
        document.getElementById("output").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tempName + "<br/>");
      }
    }
  }

  function dummy(str) {
    return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>";
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
Type a name here:
<input id="input" type="text" />
<br/>
<div id="output" />
```

Comment: Ohh.. I mistakenly forgot to add that in this code snippet :( I have that array index in my original code but still its not working. Any other suggestion? It will be a great help.

Comment: I think I need more insight into what, specifically, your code isn't doing, and any error messages you're seeing on the console. I updated the example in my answer so you can see how you can work with multiple values in the array.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help. But now I am getting an error, "document.getElementById(...) is null"... For the line, "document.getElementById("output").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tempName + "<br/>");".. Any suggestion?

Comment: For my example, that line only works because I have an element in the HTML with "output" as its ID value. `<div id="output" />` You could add a similar element to your page.

Comment: I need to bind the returned bold value to the array of objects, where the returned bold name is an attribute of each object. It is returning NULL because, at the loading time, the whole array of objects is not having its returned list of BOLD name. I need to use this (person.name BOLD) in ng-repeat. I can not bind name attribute with, document.getElementById("output").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tempName + "<br/>");..... Any suggestion?

Comment: can you please help in this context? I have one more comment